# swap data between two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a `user` table as below:

```
id     name     description

1      desc1    user1
2      desc2    user2
```

Now i want to swap the values using mysql as below:

```
id     name     description

1      user1    desc1    
2      user2    desc2
```

I found most of the examples for sqlserver but not for mysql.

I tried using:

```
 UPDATE user 
 SET name = description,  
     description = name
```

but ended up with all description values.I tried declaring temp variable using `Declare` as in sql server but there is not `declare` in Mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ýou can try like this:

```
UPDATE `user`
SET name=(@temp:=name), name = `description`, `description` = @temp
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93051b/1)**

**On a side note:**

Try to avoid naming your tables which are [keywords or reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html). In your case `User` is a *keyword* in MYSQL.

Comment: Its just a sample table name, for me zero rows are being effected with your statement

Comment: @user1770589:- It works, I have added the demo link as well. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a temporary table like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_user_table AS (SELECT id,name FROM user);
UPDATE user SET name=description;
UPDATE user u JOIN tmp_user_table tmp on u.id=tmp.id SET u.description=tmp.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this query...

```
update demo as d,(select description from demo where id = 1) as y,(select name from demo where id = 1) as z SET d.name= y.description,d.description = z.name where d.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried on SQL SERVER 2019, **NOT** **MYSQL**

```
UPDATE table_name SET COLUMN_ONE = COLUMN_TWO, COLUMN_TWO = COLUMN_ONE
```

This will swap data from `column_one` to `column_two` and the opposite,
No need to create a new table or temporary column.

[For reference](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2019/07/16/sql-server-swap-column-values-in-table/#:%7E:text=SET%20Col1%20%3D%20Col2%2C%20Col2%20%3D,storage%20location%20in%20SQL%20Server.).